# How do I push my existing repo to a fork of another repo?

Tags: git, github

I have been working on a project, and I maintain a git repo for the project on GitHub.

However, my workplace has now created a repository for this project and asked me to send a PR there. I have forked this new repository.

My initial instinct was to clone this fork and copy paste all the files from my original project, and push. But doing so, I will lose all my commits.

Is there a better way? Like to push my existing repo to this fork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending if the repositories have same history you can just add new origin.

Firstly check current git remote:

```
git remote -v
origin git@my-old-git.com:repo/path/repo.git (fetch)
origin git@my-old-git.com:repo/path/repo.git (push)
```

Then add new remote

```
git remote add origin2 git@my-new-git.com:repo/path/repo.git
```

Now you can push with

```
git push origin2 my-branch
```

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful :D

Answer (score 1):

First, clone your new forked repo.

Then add your previous repo as a remote

```
git remote add old-origin <path>
git fetch old-origin
```

Then pull your previous repo commit

```
git pull old-origin master --rebase
```

After that push to your new forked repo

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the support! This works, but the only issue is, I'd have to install all dependancies and do all configurations to get the project to run. I think adding the fork's url as a remote to existing local repo is easier (Although this can give a merge conflict, and may need to fix it).

Thanks again for the answer!